# Publish to Glassfish server stucks at 15% and all the other progresses are blocked

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, publishing

When I try to run a project (Only this project and others work fine), it always stucks at the publishing(copy and paste point). It can work perfectly fine until one time I(not sure) accidentally click incrementally publish and then stop it forcefully. Then this problem persists. I try to clean the server and also try to empty the domain folder but none of them works. It is like very strange bug.
I don't want to try creating a new domain since I have add JAAS configuration and JNDI in this domain. Or can anyone tell me how to import the configuration into a new domain?

[image: stuck at publishing progress]

If I wait long time for it to finish, random problem occurs:
[image: result1]
[image: result2]

The problem is other project can be run in debug and this project also can previously. It is all just out of sudden when I forcefully stop some process in eclipse tho I am not sure whether it is because of.
This is so annoying and can anyone give some constructive advice? Thx a lot!
Anyone encountering similar situation and sharing his/her experience here will be appreciated. It does not have to be exactly same and any lead or hint are welcome, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think it is definitely an eclipse bug.
Creating a new workspace and importing all the related projects and glassfish servers can solve the problems though I don't know the actual reason.